# Visual Studio 2017 installer stuck on win10SDK but its not there

Tags: visual-studio-2017, installation, vsix

I ran a VSIX not knowing that it would try to intall win10SDK on my vs2017. So I canceled it. Now when I try to run vs2017 it tells me the installation is not finished. When I go to the installer and click modify, it attempts to install win10SDK, and just gets stuck there. I cant enter visual studio and found no solution online, is there a way to stop the installer from trying to find/install win10SDK.
Im running a windows 8.1

Comment: install SDK on your own via ISO/WebInstaller: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk can you now resume VS 2017 setup

Comment: I wanted a solution where i did not have to install the SDK. But I kept waiting and all worked out.